# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "[object Object]". Use mongoose.model(name, schema) at Mongoose.model

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Missing Schema Error: Schema hasn't been registered for model "[object Object]".
Use mongoose model(name, schema)
at Mongoose model
error occurred

need solution for this problem

Comment: Can you show us how you defined your model and how you imported them ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in `./src/models/channel.js` file:

```js
const { Schema, model } = require("mongoose");

// Discord' channel model
const channelSchema = new Schema({
  identifier: { type: String, required: true    },
  message:    { type: String, default: "ping !" },
  guild:      { type: String, required: true    },
  type:       { type: String, required: true    },
  mode:       { type: Boolean                   }
});

module.exports = model("Channel", channelSchema);
```

in other files:

```js
const Channel = require("../models/channel");

const toto = await Channel.create({
  identifier: 1,
  guild: "toto",
  type: "tata",
});
console.log(toto);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
const mongoose=require('mongoose')
var Schema = mongoose.Schema


const productSchema=new Schema({ 
    name:{
        type:String,
        required:[true, "please enter product name"]
    },
    description:{
        type: String,
        required:[true, "please enter product Description"]
    },
 created At:{
       type: Date,
       default: Date. now
    }
})
module. exports=mongoose. model("product", product Schema)
```

**After Mongoose. model() put model Name and then Schema**

**hoping you Got The Solution**